# How to get taxonomy term name from a queried object

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

So I'm trying to achieve the following.

My code so far..

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'vehicle_listing_title');
function vehicle_listing_title( $title ) 
{
  if ( get_post_type() == 'vehicles' )
  {
    $location = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'vehicle_location');
    $model = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'vehicle_model');
    $title = $model . 'used cars for sale in' . $location .'on'. get_bloginfo('name');
  }
  return $title;
}
```

1. This code results in `$location` & `$model` being an object containing the following `term_id =>,name=>,slug=>,term_group=>,etc` so I want to get the `name` part of it.
   How do I do that?
2. What do I have to add to the code to still return the modified `$title` even when there aren't any posts assigned to the queried taxonomies?

Comment: To get a property from an object you use $object->property. In your case `$location->name`. Not sure what you mean in point 2.

Comment: okay, but where in the code do I put that? what I'm trying to say in point 2 is that, the code above is only effective when there are cars listed. I want the code to still be effective even when there aren't any listings yet. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'vehicle_listing_title');

function vehicle_listing_title( $title ) 
{
  if ( get_post_type() == 'vehicles' )
  {
    $location = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'vehicle_location');
    $model = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'vehicle_model');
    $title = '';

    if($model && $model[0]) $title .= $model[0]->name . ' used';
    else $title .= 'Used';

    $title .= ' cars for sale';

    if($location && $location[0]) $title .= ' in ' . $location[0]->name;

    $title .= ' on ' . get_bloginfo('name');

    return $title;
  }

  return $title;
}
```

Basically, you need to construct your title using IF's to check if the terms array could be obtained for the model and the location. Also, wp_terms() returns an array of term arrays, hence why you also need to obtain the first element of the result using a `[0]` index, and then chaining the `['name']` index to get the name of the term.

Comment: According to the documentation, `get_the_terms` returns an array of objects. This implies you can't use `['name']` you will have to use `->name`

Comment: Okay, I tried it. it still don't work. the code returns  `Fatal error: cannot use object of type stdClass as array in functions.php`

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't check the edited code. It works now. Thanks alot. this leaves me with point 2. So what happens, is that the previous title settings still show up when there is `nothing found` in the post type. I want your code to work even when the is `nothing found`. Is this possible? or is that just how it's suppose to be

Comment: To do that just remove the `if ( get_post_type() == 'vehicles' ){` and its corresponding `}` closing bracket, as well as the now duplicate `return $title;` statement. However, I'd advise against that, as it will make all the titles of all your pages/post to be "Used cars for sale on [blog name]". It's best to only do this for the "vehicles" post type, as you're currently doing.

Comment: Ah I see. I'd rather leave it as it is then.